# Quick way to check if a number is in a modular multiplicative cyclic group.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to check if $11$ is in the cyclic group generated by  $3$ modulo $100$. that is if there is a $k$ such that $3^k\equiv11\bmod100$. Is there a fast or interseting way to check this, if not a reason would be nice. Also is there a way to check for a given $a$ for which values of $b$; $a$ lies in the multiplicative cyclic group generated by $b$??

Thanks in advance and Regards.

Comment: For small numbers, any method will do. For big numbers, this is the notorious "discrete logarithm problem", and no one knows whether there is a fast way to do it.

Comment: Are you only interested in knowing if such a $\,k\,$ *exists*, or are you also interested in computing $k$ too?

Comment: I only want to know if it exists.

Comment: but what you put before was interesting

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question, perhaps with subliminal influence of the words "discrete  logarithm" dancing below it in the first comment.

Comment: No problem, no harm done, I still would like an answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a *necessary* condition that is easy to check.

If 
$$\left(\frac {\alpha}{b}\right) = 1 ~~\hbox{and}  ~~\left(\frac {\beta}{b}\right) = -1 ~\Rightarrow \forall k, \alpha^k \not \equiv \beta \mod b$$

where $\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$ is the Legendre symbol.

*Note:* This does not address the specific problem you have but is a general statement.

*Note 2:* If $b$ is not a prime use the Jacobi symbol instead.

Comment: why is it a requirement? I'm sorry but I don't understand.

Comment: Jacobi/Legendre symbols are multiplicative. So of symbol for $\alpha = 1$ then symbol for $\alpha^k = 1^k$ so can never be -1 or zero.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, we have an easy way to check it.

There is no $k$ such that 
$$3^k\equiv 11\ (\text{mod 100}).$$

If the rightmost digit of $3^k$ is $1$, $k$ has to be a multiple of $4$, so let us consider 
$$3^{4l}={81}^l.$$
However, the rightmost two digits are
$$81, 81\times 81\rightarrow 61, 61\times 81\rightarrow 41, 41\times 81\rightarrow 21, 21\times 81\rightarrow 01, 01\times 81\rightarrow 81.$$